# Rails - using query_reviewer with a JSON web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use **query_reviewer** gem to analyze mysql queries. It seems like the only way to access the output is by injecting the results into a view. My rails app only **returns JSON** and has no views.

Are there alternate ways to view the data?

Comment: How do you want to analyze mysql queries?

Comment: log the results into a different log file

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the gem, but its [documentation](https://github.com/nesquena/query_reviewer) explains a feature to configure it to *not* write the output to a view.

In `config/query_reviewer.yml`:

```
inject_view: false
```

Then in the part that makes the json, use the `query_review_output` helper; best escape this to JSON: `query_review_output.to_json`. This would go in the view that generates the JSON. If you don't have it, consider adding it to the output of the JSON in the controler:

```
def show
  @my_current_model = MyCurrentModel.find(params[:id])
  @output = @my_current_model.to_json
  @output.merge!({query_review_output: query_review_output })
  render json: @output
end
```